# How can UIView access property of UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, ios4

There is a `UIViewController`, it has an instance variable of `NSInteger`. I declare it in the `UIViewController.h` file as:

```
NSInterger *theNum;
...
@property NSInteger *theNum;
```

Then, I synthesize it in its `.m` file:

```
@synthesize theNum;
```

The view (`UIView`) of this `UIViewController` has a method `doSomething` that needs to access the value of `theNum`.

Here is the code in this "view"'s `.m` file:

```
-(void)doSomething {

NSInteger *myNum = self.superview.theNum; //error: request for member 'theNum' in something not a structure or union

// do something

}
```

So, how can I get the value of `theNum` from `UIViewController` to its `UIView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to pass the number from the `UIViewController` to the `UIView`. The controller should know about the view and not the other way around.

```
//SomeView.h
@interface SomeView : UIView
NSInteger theNum; 
//You have NSInteger *theNum. I am guessing you made that a pointer by accident
}

@property(assign) NSInteger theNum;

@end

//SomeViewController.m

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   ((SomeView*)self.view).theNum = theNum;//This theNum belongs to the ViewController
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would say that usually who would `doSomething` would be the view controller, while the view just `drawStuff`.

but anyway, the `superview` is not the view controller, it's the view to which you added this view as a subview.
The view usually doesn't have any pointers to the view controller because usually it's assumed that it'll basically just draw itself and its subviews.

If you really want the view itself to `doSomething`, you could maybe add a `viewController` property on your view class and set it when the view controller creates the view.

Comment: Adding a view controller to the view would be ill-advised.

Comment: @joshpaul I agree, that's why I wrote the first four paragraphs.